# How can I add a column to a specific position in a csv file using cat, sed, awk or cut?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I've got a csv file with this content:

```
   col1, col2, col5
    1,    1,    1
    2,    2,    2
    3,    3,    3
    4,    4,    4
```

I need to add a column in the third position of the file with a header but with empty values.

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,    1,        ,   1
2,    2,        ,   2
3,    3,        ,   3
4,    4,        ,   4
```

Is there any way to do it using one of the Linux commands like cat, sed, awk or cut?

I know that with cut is possible to modify a file by columns cut -d , -f1,2,3  file1 > file2. But it seems does not have an option to add a custom column.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Inian Thanks. I've just added that I've tried with the cut command. However, I don't find a way to add a custom column.

Comment: You have a typo in original file, it is `col5` in first and `col4` in later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best I could do with `awk`

```
$  awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'BEGIN{print "col1, col2, col3, col4"} NR>1{k=$3; $3="\t"; $4=k; print $0}' newfile
col1, col2, col3, col4
    1,    1,    ,    1
    2,    2,    ,    2
    3,    3,    ,    3
    4,    4,    ,    4
```

You could write it to a new file using the redirection operator (`> newfile` at the end)

The logic is straight-forward:-

- `-v FS=',' -v OFS=','` sets the input and output field separator to comma(`,`)
- `BEGIN{print "col1, col2, col3, col4"}` creates a new header with the updated column name, remember the `BEGIN` block in `awk` is executed before actual processing of the file
- For the `<action>` part in `awk`, `NR>1{k=$3; $3="\t"; $4=k; print $0}` am skipping the header from the original file, taking a backup of the 3rd column in `k`, over-writing it and replacing with a empty `tab-space` and 4th column is restored as the older 3rd column value.

Another cool suggestion by [`fedorqui`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) in the comments, the following even simpler way to do it.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1{$0="col1, col2, col3, col4"} NR>1{$3=sprintf("\t,%s",$3)}1' file
col1, col2, col3, col4
    1,    1,    ,    1
    2,    2,    ,    2
    3,    3,    ,    3
    4,    4,    ,    4
```

Comment: `print $0` is unnecessary. Just say `NR>1 { things } 1` and the `1` will trigger the print action.

Comment: @fedorqui: thanks for the catch! I already tried that, I realized I am skipping the header part and doing some local actions within the `{things}`, and if I do `{}1` it is screwing up my output with entire file content.

Comment: Well, replacing  `NR==1` skipping it and printing in the `BEGIN` block is a bit strange. I would use `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1{$0="col1, col2, col3, col4"} NR>1{$3=sprintf("\t,%s",$3)}1' file` instead. Note the usage of `sprintf` to format as required.

Comment: @fedorqui: Well `NR==1{$0="col1, col2, col3, col4"}` this solves the problem I was facing, Will update the answer, BTW, cool use of `sprintf`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v f=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$f = (NR>1?"":"col"f) FS $f} 1' file
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,1,,1
2,2,,2
3,3,,3
4,4,,4
```

The above was run on this file:

```
$ cat file
col1,col2,col4
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
```

add white space to taste...

Answer (score 0):

If there really is space before the first column like the question shows, let's abuse it:

```
$ awk -F"(,* +)" '{for(i=j=1; ++j<NF; i++) $i=$j; $i=""} NR==1 {$3="col3"; OFS=","} 1' file
col1,col2,col3,col5
1,1,,1
2,2,,2
3,3,,3
4,4,,4
```

If not:

```
$ awk '{$(NF+=1)=$NF; $(NF-1)=(NR==1?"col3":"")","} 1' file
col1, col2, col3, col5
1, 1, , 1
2, 2, , 2
3, 3, , 3
4, 4, , 4
```